# Issues with Django data serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My simple models.py looks like this :

```
from django.db import models 

class Prescription(models.Model):
    pr_id = models.CharField()
    date_prescribed = models.DateTimeField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey()
    pharmacy = models.ForeignKey()
```

What I need is the total count of prescriptions issued grouped by month.
The queryset that I came up with for the above requirement is as follows:

```
prescriptions = Prescription.objects.extra(select={'month': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_prescribed')}).filter(date_prescribed__range=(start_date,end_date)).values('month').annotate(Count('pr_id')).order_by('month')
```

where end_date is today's date and start_date is the date six month's back.This queryset works as expected and I have confirmed this on the django shell.

I need this data in a JSON format since it eventually needs to be sent to a line chart in Angular.I am using Django Rest framework for my serialization. My views.py looks like this :

```
from django.db import connection
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.db.models import Count
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from testproj.models.Prescription import Prescription 
from testproj.serializers.AnalyticsSerializer import LineGraphSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def prescription_trend_overview(request):

    end_date = date.today()
    start_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)
    prescriptions = Prescription.objects.extra(select={'month': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_prescribed')}).filter(date_prescribed__range=(start_date,end_date)).values('month').annotate(Count('pr_id')).order_by('month')
    serializer = LineGraphSerializer(prescriptions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and my serializer.py looks like this :

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class LineGraphSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total_prescriptions = serializers.IntegerField()    
    timeline = serializers.DateField()
```

However,the data i finally get in the DRF page on the browser shows everything as null.[image]

I suspect the issue is with serialization because the queryset works properly.Any help

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't leave comments, so..

I do not understand much about that QuerySet, but, try this:

```
class LineGraphSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total_prescriptions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()   
    timeline = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_prescriptions(self,*args, **kwargs):
        #print kwargs and look data
        #return <requiere data>

    def get_timeline(self,*args, **kwargs):
        #print kwargs and look data
        #return <requiere data>
```

PD 1: Could you give us printed QuerySet at shell?

PD 2: I can't leave comments yet, sorry again